# CSS - Customising and arranging Flexsiders buttons

Tags: css, html, flexslider

Im so new to web design, CSS and html5 but im trying to learn. I reacently downloaded "FLEXSIDER" but i cant figure out how to arrange the buttons how i want. Any help would be so much appreciated. Here is an image of what im trying to achive:

[image]
Here is the html:

```
<!-- Banner Start -->
<div class="bannerFrame dropShadow">
<div class="bannerBg clearfix"><!--<img src="images/banner_images/a.jpg">--></div>
<span class="bannerBgShadow"></span>
<div class="cdContainer clearfix">
<div class="cdplayer clearfix">
<ul>
  <li><a href=""><span class="revPlayBtn"></span>
    <!--<p>Prev</p>-->
    <!--<span class="iconShadow"></span>--> </a></li>
  <li><a href=""><span class="playBtn"></span>
    <!--<p>Play</p>-->
    <!--<span class="iconShadow"></span>--> </a></li>
  <li><a href=""><span class="stopBtn"></span>
    <!--<p>Stop</p>-->
    <!--<span class="iconShadow"></span>--> </a></li>
  <li><a href=""><span class="fwBtn"></span>
    <!--<p>Next</p>-->
    <!--<span class="iconShadow"></span>--> </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Banner End -->
```

And this is the CSS I'm Using:

```
/* =================  Banner Start ================= */
.bannerFrame {
background:#f7f7f7 /*rgba(210,210,210,1)*/;
border-top:1px solid #ccc;
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
padding:25px 0 15px 0;
min-height:300px;
}
.bannerBg img {
height: 487.5px;
margin: auto;
overflow: auto;
position: absolute;
width: 932.5px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}
.bannerBg{
background:/*#00AEEF*/ rgba(0, 174, 239, 0.5);
border:15px solid #fff;
height:487.5px;
min-height:487.5px;
margin:0px auto 0px auto;
/*outline:2px solid rgba(200,200,200,0.5);*/
position: relative;
text-align:center;
width:932.5px;
/* Box Shadows */
box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);    
}
.bannerBgShadow {
background:url(../images/elements/bannerShadow.png) no-repeat;
display:block;
height:20px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top:0px;
width:1100px;
}
/* =================  Banner End ================= */

.cdplayer ul {
color:#999;
font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
letter-spacing:1px;
text-align:center;
}
.cdplayer li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px 20px 0 0;
}
.cdplayer li a {
color: #999;
text-decoration: none;
}
.cdplayer li a:hover {
color: #00AEEF;
text-decoration: none;
}
.cdplayer li a span.revPlayBtn {
background:url(images/icons/rewIcon.svg) no-repeat;
display:block;
height:41px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 0 0 5px 0;
width:41px;
}
.cdplayer li a:hover span.revPlayBtn {
background:url(images/icons/rewIconHover.svg) no-repeat;
}
.cdplayer li a span.playBtn {
background:url(images/icons/playIcon.svg) no-repeat;
display:block;
height:41px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 0 0 5px 0;
width:41px;
}
.cdplayer li a:hover span.playBtn {
background:url(images/icons/pauseIconHover.svg) no-repeat;
}
.cdplayer li a span.fwBtn {
background:url(images/icons/ffIcon.svg) no-repeat;
display:block;
height:41px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 0 0 5px 0;
width:41px;
}
.cdplayer li a:hover span.fwBtn {
background:url(images/icons/ffIconHover.svg) no-repeat;
}
.cdplayer li a span.stopBtn {
background:url(images/icons/stopIcon.svg) no-repeat;
display:block;
height:41px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 0 0 5px 0;
width:41px;
}
.cdplayer li a:hover span.stopBtn {
background:url(images/icons/stopIconHover.svg) no-repeat;
}
.cdplayer li:nth-child(2) {
padding-right: 10px;
}
.cdplayer li:nth-child(3) {
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please consider posting your code to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). It will be way more easy to help you if we can see the actual code in action.

Comment: as per request here is my code on jsfiddle: [link] http://jsfiddle.net/MarcusOlley/Anmzt/

Comment: And include the assets with FlexSlider and all that CSS too.

Comment: Its to all to big and i have started to add the flexslider yet cause i dont know how to but here is the [link] http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Comment: ooppss "I havent started to add the flexslider"